# GCC Linking with .o file

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, linker, object-files

I'm trying to compile my code but it isn't working. I got this to compile at school but I can't compile this on my home computer. I can't seem to figure out why. I need this error fixed in order to continue my assignment. Also, ***this list.o file is the profs file. I have to use this file.***

Solutions I've tried kind of? 
I've updated gcc to gcc-7. 
I've located libc.a

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a
/usr/share/doc/libklibc/README.klibc.arch
```

Edit: I have tried compiling without -fPIC

```
gcc -m64 -pthread -Wall -std=c99 -o run main.o as2.o list.o
/usr/bin/ld: list.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against undefined symbol...
```

This is from the terminal:

```
gcc -m64 -pthread -Wall -std=c99 -fPIC  -o run main.o as2.o list.o
/usr/bin/ld: list.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against undefined symbol `headlist' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is my make file:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -m64 -pthread -Wall -std=c99 -fPIC 
PROG = run
OBJS = main.o as2.o list.o

run: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(PROG) $(OBJS)

main.o: main.c list.h as2.h
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c

as2.o: as2.c as2.h list.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c as2.c

clean:
    rm main.o as2.o run
```

This is my includes:

```
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <netdb.h>  
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 
#include "list.h"
#include "as2.h"
```

Any ideas/solutions?

Comment: My guess is that `list.o` is compiled without `-fPIC` and mixing objects with and without this flag is not a good idea. Try recompiling _without_ that flag.

Comment: @rodrigo Thanks for replying! i forgot to mention that I have tried compiling without -fPIC before too. It still wouldn't work.
gcc -m64 -pthread -Wall -std=c99 -o run main.o as2.o list.o
/usr/bin/ld: list.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against undefined symbo

Comment: Mmmm, the line you added in the edit is not compiling anything, it is linking. You can try compiling and linking all your files without `-fPIC`, just in case...

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. I think i should have been more clear about the problem. When I'm trying to link the .o files with my profs list.o, it's giving me this error ass seen in the description. I have tried manipulating the -fPIC in various places and it still gives me the same error. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Tell us what is the OS + version on which you could compile this at school and what is the OS + version with which you cannot compile it at home. Also the GCC versions.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:
changed the spelling from `LFLAGS` to `LDFLAGS` to appease some comment.

EDIT:
moved the `-c` option to appease some comment.

Note: `all` is normally the first target in a make file.

Note: used `:=` rather than `=` so the macros would only be evaluated once.

Note: the `list.o` is already available in the current directory (per the OPs question) so is not compiled in the makefile.  But is only linked with the other object files to produce the executable

your makefile seems to have a few oversights.  Suggest:

```
CC := gcc
RM := rm -f

CFLAGS := -ggdb -m64 -pthread -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99
#LDFLAGS :=   <-- use the default value

PROG := run
OBJS := main.o as2.o list.o
HDRS := list.h as2.h



.PSEUDO: all clean

all: $(PROG)

$(PROG): $(OBJS)
    $(CC)  -ggdb -o $(PROG) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)

main.o: main.c $(HDRS)
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c -o main.o -I.

as2.o: as2.c $(HDRS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c as2.c -o as2.o -I.

clean:
    $(RM) main.o as2.o run
```

Comment: Don't put `-c` in `CFLAGS`, it limits where it can be used. Also, don't you want to explain to a beginner what changes you've made and why?

Comment: IMO: DO put the -c flag in CFLAGS, why, because compiling is the ONLY time that CFLAGS should ever be mentioned.  For linking, there is the LFLAGS (which should be placed near the end of the link command line)

Comment: hey user362949, what's -ggdb, -m64, -Wextra, -pendantic, -I. ? How will these help me in my case?

Comment: your make file doesn't have a separator?  @user362949

Comment: I assume you mean `LDFLAGS` not `LFLAGS`, and GNU Make's [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html) add `-c` to the rule, not to `CFLAGS`, and also uses `CFLAGS` in the `LINK.c` rule (which compiles _and_ links in one step, so uses both `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`). So your choice is unconventional, and doesn't match common usage.

Comment: @elam, what do you mean by 'a separator'.   regarding: ` -ggdb, -m64, -Wextra, -pendantic`  the `-ggdb` is to specialize the .o file for the `gdb` debugger.  The `-m64` means the underlying architecture is a 64bit machine.  The `-Wextra` enables a lot more of the compiler warnings (IMO: should always use it).  Suggest read 'https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options'  (cont)

Comment: (cont)  -pedantic: "Issue all the warnings demanded by strict ISO C and ISO C++; reject all programs that use forbidden extensions, and some other programs that do not follow ISO C and ISO C++. For ISO C, follows the version of the ISO C standard specified by any -std option used.

without this option, certain GNU extensions and traditional C and C++ features are supported as well. With this option, they are rejected.  (cont)

Comment: the `-I<directory>`  tells the compiler where to (additionally) look for header files.  The `.` is the current directory